# App not sleeping after idleTimer time expires

Tags: ios

From what I understand the idleTimerDisabled setting is set to a default of NO. Although, when I run my app and wait for it to time out and sleep, it's not timing out and it's not sleeping.

I've gone into my AppDelegate and set it to NO manually to try to force it to sleep but still no luck. I'm using the code below...

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
```

Any thoughts about why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you running your test build through XCode via tethered USB?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run the app from the iOS device itself, not from the XCode debugger. The debugger will not allow the device to go to sleep because you're, well, debugging ;)

Comment: Not a mistake... just a slight miss. :)

Comment: Wow - if I'm going to get downvoted after nearly 2 years an explanation would be appreciated. lol

Comment: @Dan someone just wanted to rain on your parade I guess. I bumped ya.